# How to find which coordinate in image that closest to the corner in python?

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing

I have a 2D array, `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3],, ..., [xn, yn]]`,(n < 20). **These arrays are pair of coordinate in an image**.

Which coordinates are closest to the top right corner, bottom right corner, and bottom left corner?

**Example:**

`arr = [[634  974] [1089 1721] [171 1719] [1092  228]]`

**expected result:**

closest to top right corner = `[1092, 228]`

closest to bottom right corner = `[1089, 1721]`

closest to bottom left corner = `[171, 1719]`

i have few approaches:

- max X and max Y
- highest value of the sum of x and y, then smallest value of the ratio of x and y

idk, i really confused what is the best approach. i've tried this:

```
max_x, max_y = arr.max(axis=0)
min_x,min_y = arr.min(axis=0)

print("max X and min Y:",[max_x,min_y])
print("max X and max Y:",[max_x,max_y])
print("min X and max Y:",[min_x,max_y])
```

but the result of closest to bottom right corner is [1092, 1721]. And that makes the coordinate messed up

Comment: i made an edit to the question. i need the result in pairs because it is a coordinate. ex: what's the coordinate of in the highest X and also in the lowest Y? something like that

Comment: The top right corner of what? The bounding box? Or do you have specific coordinates for these corners?

Comment: @CrisLuengo the corner of the image

Comment: Ok, so you have the sizes of the image, which means you have their coordinates. I can write an answer later.

Comment: @CrisLuengo exactly, thanks in advance

Comment: The linked duplicate does what I was thinking of. You do the same process for each of the four corners of the image.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks, i've tried that solution and it works well so far

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting any results because iterating over a list of lists will result working on one list each time,
meaning, if I iterate over your `arr` the first value of `i` will be `[634,974]` so obviously the maximum of `[634]` is 634...
To solve it we can use 2 arrays, one holding the x values, the other holding the y values.
on those arrays we want to find the maximum and minimum.
SO! lets implement it!

```
arr = [[634, 974], [1176, 1854], [94, 1853], [1176, 95]]
x_values = []
y_values = []
for pair in arr:
    x_values.append(pair[0]) #appending the x values
    y_values.append(pair[1]) # same for y
    
#now that we have all of our values sorted we can find the max and min:
print(max(x_values))
print(min(y_values))
```

Comment: i need the result in pair, not individually. because it is a coordinate

Answer (score 0):

For mathematical purposes try using NumPy arrays, they are superior in every way! Also while indexing, you have to specify columns and rows, put a ":" on the first input to call all columns with the specified rows:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[634, 974], [1176, 1854], [94, 1853], [1176, 95]])

print(np.max(arr[:,0]))  # for max x
print(np.min(arr[:,0]))

print(np.max(arr[:,1]))  # for max y
print(np.min(arr[:,1]))
```

Out:
1176
94
1854
95

Comment: i need the result in pair, not individually. because it is a coordinate

Comment: Well, you can simply put these results into another array :)

`pair1 = np.array([np.max(arr[:, 0]), np.min(arr[:, 0])])`
`pair2 = np.array([np.max(arr[:, 1]), np.min(arr[:, 1])])`

... etc